# ms access query very slow

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have this ms access query:

```
SELECT t1.sb, suchbegriff2, menge
FROM (SELECT artnr & '/' & [lfdnr-kal] AS sb, left(suchbegriff,7) &
         val(right(suchbegriff,4)) AS suchbegriff2 
      FROM kvks 
      WHERE suchbegriff like '*/*')  AS t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT artnr & '/' & [lfdnr-kal] AS sb, 
                 [artnr-hz] & '/' & val(lfdnr) AS hz, menge 
            FROM konf 
            WHERE [artnr-hz]<>'')  AS t2 
      ON (t1.sb=t2.sb) AND (t1.suchbegriff2=t2.hz);
```

It runs really very slow (over 30 sec.). I figured out, it is because the `inner join` part. If I leave this, the speed is correct.

Maybe it is because of the fact slow, that the joined fields are calculated expressions?

**EDIT:**

I modified the query based on the answer of Smandoli:

```
SELECT kvks.artnr & '/' & kvks.[lfdnr-kal] AS sb, 
    left(suchbegriff,7) & val(right(suchbegriff,4)) AS suchbegriff2, 
    konf.menge
FROM kvks, konf
WHERE kvks.suchbegriff like '*/*' 
    and konf.[artnr-hz]<>'' 
    and kvks.artnr=konf.artnr 
    and kvks.[lfdnr-kal]=konf.[lfdnr-kal] 
    and left(suchbegriff,7) & val(right(suchbegriff,4))=[artnr-hz] & '/' & val(lfdnr)
```

It runs now correct.

Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a complicated mess with those calculated fields.  Why not join more directly?  This query below leaves one `'/'` unaccounted for, but should tell you what I'm thinking of.

```
SELECT 
   t1.sb, 
   left(st1.uchbegriff,7) & val(right(t1.suchbegriff,4)) AS suchbegriff2, 
   t1.menge 

FROM kvks AS t1     
INNER JOIN konf AS t2 

WHERE (t1.suchbegriff like '*/*')
    AND (t2.artnr-hz<>'')
    AND (t1.artnr=t2.artnr) 
    AND (t1.lfdnr-kal=t2.lfdnr-kal) 
    AND (left(t1.suchbegriff,7)=t1.[artnr-hz]) 
    AND (val(right(t1.suchbegriff,4))=val(t2.hz));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the inner join, you can try to use a saved query (or temp table) instead of writing the query at run time.

So, I would first try to abstract this query

```
SELECT artnr & '/' & [lfdnr-kal] AS sb, 
                 [artnr-hz] & '/' & val(lfdnr) AS hz, menge 
            FROM konf 
            WHERE [artnr-
            hz]<>'')  AS t2 
      ON (t1.sb=t2.sb) AND (t1.suchbegriff2=t2.hz)
```

Second of all, if possible, I would abstract some of the functions in the queries. You could do this with VBA, or manipulating the data outside of the queries.

Third, you could always create a field on your table that combines the two fields together that you need.

E.x: Make a new column in your `konf` table that stores the value of `artnr & '/' & [lfdnr-kal]`

What you need to do is limit the functions/calculations/coalescing of fields *at run time*. That's a lot for a query to do, and if it's running slow I would see a direction correlation either between that, or something incorrect with your indexes/joins.

If you've identified this as a join issue, you can use VBA to spin up a temp table with your queries, and use those as the record source instead of the SQL. 
Also, if you don't utilize a temp table, at least *save the queries*. This allows Access to have a plan for running the queries, whereas your query is 100% run-time dependent.

Comment: The saved query improve just the readibility, and not the performance.  Normally in a dinamic contest of programmation, they decrease the performance, because with a built ad-hoc query you can put filter at each level of subquery. Second place the database are born to join tables.  It is their job. The problem is that the join fields must be indexed.  The  decrease of the time is logarithmic on base 2. It means that if a query take 30000 mills to perform, if you index the join fields you reach  Log2(30000)=14 mills... ein augenblink.

Comment: I'm going to agree with you, but also disagree. MS Access saves execution plans for saved queries. As long as you are refreshing the execution plan when the data changes, these should be optimized over queries that aren't saved. You can also compact/repair the database to recalculate the execution plans

Answer (score 0):

Your query runs slow because of "Nesting" and then "Joining". You can try creating the temp tables and used that table in query. Creating temp table is good practice rather than making the query complex.

Comment: If you mean temp tables like in SQL Server, I believe in MS Access you have to use real tables.  To make them work you have to run successive routines, typically using VBA; you can't just launch a set of procedures in a stack, as you may be used to.

Comment: Yes you can create the temp table from original table but you need to run the VBA to refresh that data. The more information for that is explained in https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/07/20/use-temp-tables-in-your-code-for-quick-and-easy-analysis/

Answer (score -1):

99999!!! I think you have just to implement some index

```
 (t1.sb=t2.sb) AND (t1.suchbegriff2=t2.hz);
```

these ones are very suspicious. Are the 4 indexed?